# Docker and Laravel

Tags: laravel, docker

On my Laravel application using docker I have containerized both composer and artisan away from my php container.

How do I get the composer and artisan containers to communicate with each other, namely composer to artisan? As after as composer install, the artisan commands in my composer.json fail.

```
"post-autoload-dump": [
  "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
  "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
],
```

Any ideas!?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check [user-defined bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks) to communicate containers  running on the same Docker host.

Comment: I use Trafik to bridge my networks/containers in docker-compose.yml https://github.com/containous/traefik-library-image,  Maybe this will help you in getting them to talk.